# Android Memory Leak management says "Don use non-static inner classes" but this comes with a side effect

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, static

Lets say I have an inner class that I make static, so I avoid memory leaks.
Now, this inner class wants to use a method from the main class, but in order for me to do that, I need to make that method static as well because "you cannot use non-static method in a static context". And if I make that method static, the fields that it uses should also become static and now a chain reaction is triggered, where everything should be changed to static, which I do not like.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private int field1;
    private int field2;


    private void doSomething() {
        field1 + field2;

    }

    private class CertainListenerImpl implements CertainListener {

        @Override
        private void onCertainEventsOccurrence() {
             doSomething();
        }


    }


}
```

If I change the inner class in the forementioned code to "static" now I have to make doSomething be static and also field1 and field2 be static.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

non-static classes can lead to unintended references to outer classes.  In your case you could pass in a reference to an outer class which would make it clearer as to what you are doing but also make your code more complex.  There is no wrong or right, I suggest you do what you believe will be less error prone.

> I have to make doSomething be static and also field1 and field2 be static.

I wouldm't do that. Instead you can pass the instance of MyFragment to the constructor to CertainListenerImpl and store this as field, which is what Java does for you.

BTW: This internal field is called `this$0` for the Oracle/OpenJDK, and if you create a field with this name it will call it `this$$0` or with more $$$$

What you have now is equivalent to

```
private static class CertainListenerImpl implements CertainListener {

    private final MyFragment this$0; // rename to taste

    CertainListenerImpl(MyFragment myFragment) {
        this$0 = myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    private void onCertainEventsOccurrence() {
         this$0.doSomething();
    }


}
```

Comment: I am just going out of my way to find a memory leak in my code right now and doing everything possible to fill all the holes I find

Comment: @J.K. This is a good idea, however in the non-android would just take a heap dump and trace the memory leak from this dump.  Are you able to take a heap dump in android?

Comment: Yes I am, but I am not very good at inspecting these yet. I try to fix things in code first.

Comment: @J.K. This is a better approach if you have enough time.

Comment: I dont understand, though. If I pass an instance of the fragment to the CertainListenerImpl's constructor, and then call doSomething using it, will the IDE not tell me to make doSomething be static again?

Comment: So I let only  the inner class be static and instead of making the other methods and fields be static, I pass an instance of the fragment to its constructor. I will try that, thanks

Comment: I worked!! The IDE does not make me change the modifier of doSomething to static!